# Rock, Paper, Scissors, ODD OUTPUT

Tags: c++, function

For my class project, we are to make a game of "rock, paper, scissors" using a function to show the menu and validate the input and a function to determine who won. My code will compile and it functions properly when I bypass the first function. But when I use both functions and I enter `1`, `2`, or `3` for my selection, it gives me `-4195200` as a value.

Any help? Here is my code:

```
// This project will be a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
int choices();
int userselect (int, int);

int main()
{

        //Variables and Seed
        int selection;
        char again;
        unsigned seed = time(0);
        srand(seed);
        int compselect = (rand()%3)+1;

        //Constants for the menu choices
        const int ROCK = 1,
                  PAPER = 2,
                  SCISSORS = 3;

        do
        {
                //Display the menu choices and validate
                choices();

                cout << "You picked " << selection << endl;
                cout << "The computer picked " << compselect << endl;

                //Display the results
                userselect(selection, compselect);

                //Replay loop
                cout << "Do you want to play again? (Y/N)";
                cin >> again;
        }
        while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');
        return 0;
}

//***********************************************************
// This function will display the menu choices and validate *
//***********************************************************

int choices()
{
        int selection;

        cout << "********************************\n";
        cout << "*   Please Select A Choice     *\n";
        cout << "*          1 - Rock            *\n";
        cout << "*          2 - Paper           *\n";
        cout << "*          3 - Scissors        *\n";
        cout << "********************************\n";
        cin >> selection;

        //Validate the selection
        while (selection < 1 || selection > 3)
        {
                cout << "ERROR: Enter a valid choice.";
                cin >> selection;
        }

        return selection;
}

//***********************************************************
// This function will display the menu choices and validate *
//***********************************************************

int userselect (int num1, int num2)
{
         // If user enters Rock
        if (num1 == 1)
        {
                if (num2 == 1)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Rock \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Rock \n";
                        cout << " TIE! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 2)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Rock \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Paper \n";
                        cout << "Paper beats Rock. YOU LOSE! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 3)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Rock \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << " Rock beats Scissors. YOU WIN! \n";
                }
        }

        // If user enters Paper
        if (num1 == 2)
        {
                if (num2 == 1)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Paper \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Rock \n";
                        cout << " Paper beats Rock. YOU WIN! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 2)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Paper \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Paper \n";
                        cout << " TIE! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 3)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Paper \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << " Scissors beats Paper. YOU LOSE! \n";
                }
}

        // If user enters Scissors
        if (num1 == 3)
        {
                if (num2 == 1)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Rock \n";
                        cout << " Rock beats Scissors. YOU LOSE! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 2)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Paper \n";
                        cout << "Scissors beat Paper. YOU WIN! \n";
                }
                else if (num2 == 3)
                {
                        cout << "You picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << "The computer picked Scissors \n";
                        cout << " TIE! \n";
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Rock, Paper, Scissors, ODD QUESTION

Comment: Title sounds like the next [`True`, `False`, `FileNotFound`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx).

Comment: Clearly the problem is that the user chose [Lizard or Spock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock).

Answer (score 2):

You're not [handling the newline that's still in the `cin` input stream](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/90228/flushing-the-input-stream), and you're not doing any error checking on the `cin >> selection` that's consequently failing. Because it's failing, `selection` is not given any new value and, since you didn't initialise it, you're getting this rubbish number `-4195200`.

You'd have seen this if you'd performed some error checking, or allowed the error checking that you sort of already have in your `while` loop to do its job by initialising `selection` to `0`:

```
int selection = 0;
```

You're also failing entirely to *store* the result of calling `choices()`, inside `main()`. Remember, the variable `selection` inside `choices()` is a local variable, and is not the same as the variable `selection` inside `main()`, to which you never assign a value, in this code:

```
selection = choices();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `selection = choices()` instead of just `choices()`

Answer (score 1):

You define `selection` in function `choices();` as local variable, but output the global `selection` in `main()`.

Replace

```
choices();
```

with

```
selection = choices();
```